# Add a new Json property to the Json String response

Tags: java, json

I have a Json response `String` like the one below.

```
{
    "arr": [
        {
            "Value": "v1",
            "id": 10456102,
            "arr1": [
                {
                    "date": "2017-09-02",
                    "c1": {
                        "a": 1287900,
                        "c": "USD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-09-03",
                    "c1": {
                        "a": 1288000,
                        "c": "USD"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here , I am trying to add a new property `flag=Set` and the final Json would look like below:

```
{
    "arr": [
        {
            "Value": "v1",
            "id": 10456102,
            "arr1": [
                {
                    "date": "2017-09-02",
                    "c1": {
                        "a": 1287900,
                        "c": "USD"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "date": "2017-09-03",
                    "c1": {
                        "a": 1288000,
                        "c": "USD"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    "flag":"set"
}
```

I have tried to get the Json object and added the new property. But it is not appending this new field.

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResponse);
jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("flag", set);
```

`jsonResponse` is a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to simply add aproperty like :

```
JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResponse);
jsonElement.set = set;
```

Or using array syntax :

```
jsonElement["set"] = set;
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my object lib:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

/**
*
* @author longdo
*/
public class JsonObject {

private static final JsonParser GSON_PARSER = new JsonParser();
private final com.google.gson.JsonObject gsonObject;

public JsonObject() {
    this(new com.google.gson.JsonObject());
}

public JsonObject(com.google.gson.JsonObject gsonObject) {
    this.gsonObject = gsonObject;
}

public JsonObject addProperty(String property, String value) {
    this.gsonObject.addProperty(property, value);
    return this;
}

public JsonObject addProperty(String property, Number value) {
    this.gsonObject.addProperty(property, value);
    return this;
}

public JsonObject addProperty(String property, Boolean value) {
    this.gsonObject.addProperty(property, value);
    return this;
}

public JsonObject add(String property, JsonObject value) {
    this.gsonObject.add(property, value.toGson());
    return this;
}

public JsonObject add(String property, JsonArray value) {
    this.gsonObject.add(property, value.toGson());
    return this;
}

public String getString(String property) {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null || je.isJsonNull()) {
        return null;
    }
    return je.getAsString();
}

public int getInt(String property) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        throw new NoSuchFieldException(property + " (getInt) not found.");
    }
    return je.getAsInt();
}

public int getInt(String property, int defaultValue) {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return je.getAsInt();
}

public long getLong(String property) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        throw new NoSuchFieldException(property + " (getLong) not found.");
    }
    return je.getAsLong();
}

public long getLong(String property, long defaultValue) {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        return defaultValue;
    }
    return je.getAsLong();
}

public boolean getBoolean(String property) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        throw new NoSuchFieldException(property + " (getBoolean) not found.");
    }
    return je.getAsBoolean();
}

public JsonObject getObject(String property) {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new JsonObject(je.getAsJsonObject());
}

public JsonArray getArray(String property) {
    JsonElement je = this.gsonObject.get(property);
    if (je == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return new JsonArray(je.getAsJsonArray());
}

public com.google.gson.JsonObject toGson() {
    return gsonObject;
}

public int size() {
    return gsonObject.size();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return gsonObject.toString();
}

public static JsonObject parse(String jsonString) {
    if (jsonString == null || jsonString.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return new JsonObject(GSON_PARSER.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject());
}
}
```

and main class:

```
 String str = "your string";
 JsonObject obj = JsonObject.parse(str);
 obj.addProperty("flag", "set");
 System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

Comment: I tried this : But no luck                                                                                                                               
                JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonResponse);
  JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
  jsonObject.addProperty("flag", "set");
  jsonResponse = jsonObject.toString();